# How do I change the site mail address?

Tags: rules, emails

I want to change my site-wide email address. To do this, I changed the settings on admin/config/system/site-information. However, when I send an email from rules, it still uses the old email address.

How can I get the new email address to be picked up?

Comment: @Geoff 1. I cleared cache and ran Cron. 2. I am using HTML Mail and regular email. 3. In Rules it says, "leave blank to use site-wide email address:, so I left it blank. However, I have also done experiment with the built in Rules token of: `[site:mail]` and creating my own token, but it's the same issue 4. Here is the URL of the rule export: http://pastebin.com/p3tRAW9K

Comment: @Geoff I am not using tokens for any of the email addresses in TO or FROM. The reason there are two addresses in TO is for debugging reasons, but it still uses the old site-wide address for FROM even when TO has only 1 address. For FROM I am not entering any email address, as if you leave it blank, it is supposed to use the default. However, it just uses the old default (even when I use a token, it still uses the old default).

Comment: @Geoff When I use `site:mail` in body text (on a node) it is correct. But in rules, it prints the old address.

Comment: ok - under the Rules Settings, Advanced - try Recheck Integrity, and Rebuild Rules' Cache... if that doesn't change anything, try add a system message with the token and see what it gives

Comment: @Geoff Thanks, I have rechecked Rules Integrity and Rebuilt Rules Cahce. The token works in the system message, but not in the email sender field.

Comment: I deleted my old comments, just to clean this up - well, we're narrowing it down. Does it happen for both html mail and the core mail?  try adding the token to the body of the message

Comment: @Geoff It happens for both core and HTML mail. If I put the token in the body, it prints fine, but for the "From" field it reverts to the old email address. If I hardcode (e.g. by typing it) the address, it works fine. However, I'd rather user a token, just incase it changes in the future.

Comment: it is sounding like a bug in Rules, or at least the mail implementation in Rules. I would suggest creating an issue in the issue queue for Rules, but I am nearly out of ideas - the only other thing that comes to mind - are you using a template for the mail, and to check the template to make sure it is set up properly

Comment: @Geoff. No, I am not using any template. As it does seem to be a Rules bug, please could you post that as your answer and I can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments, and narrowing down the problem to the Rules module itself, or its integration with the mail system:

- Tokens work elsewhere
- Tokens within the body of the message work but not the from field
- No templates are used
- Core mail as well as third-party mail are affected
- Clearing the cache, including the rules one, had no effect

It would appear to be a bug in the Rules module or the mail delivery part of it. I would suggest adding an issue to the [Rules issue queue](https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/rules?categories=All) and see if they can further explore options for correcting the problem.