# Site email change doesnt work

Tags: emails

I have changed my site email address from admin@example.com to team@example.com in config>system>site info. 
The emails are sent to user via the new account; however the core emails (such as Subject: New release(s) available for example) on my old email. 
Any idea how I might be able to change this. 
I understand that there is bug with rules [How to change Site Wide email address and get it to work in rules](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/160349/how-to-change-site-wide-email-address-and-get-it-to-work-in-rules)
but is this to do with that? 
also I understand that this might be changes through setting.php; however there are no emails accounts listed in my setting.php!
Thanks
PS: I am using the latest version of drupal commons.